# How can I upload my hex file onto my breadboard?

Tags: c, macos, terminal, macos-sierra, avrdude

Every time I execute the `make` command I get an error reading

```
avrdude -p m324p -P usb -c avrispmkII -F -U flash:w:lab7.hex
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

and so on. I am writing in C on a Mac in terminal. I tried using Xcode but can not figure it out, so I am just wondering if anyone can assist me?

Also when I use the command

```
avrdude -v -p m16 -P usb -c avrispmkII -e -F -U flash:w:lab7.hex
```

I get this

```
         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : avrispmkII
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found AVRISP mkII, serno: 000200312345
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
         AVR Part                      : ATmega16
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                            Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom         4    10   128    0 no        512    4      0  9000  9000 0xff 0xff
       flash         33     6   128    0 yes     16384  128    128  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          4    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : STK500V2
     Description     : Atmel AVR ISP mkII
     Programmer Model: AVRISP mkII
```

Comment: Have you checked elsewhere? did a quick google-fu on `avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive` to get plenty of hits... am suspecting its the usb is the cause, try another computer?

Comment: Yes I have been trying everything, I have been working on this project for weeks now and nothing seems to work.

Comment: you do have libusb installed?

Comment: yes I do, but still nothing

Comment: *Last Response* try another cable?